# Android Map Error: Couldn't get connection factory client (with a correct ApiKey)

Tags: android, gps, maps, factory

Hi the MapActivity starts and it shows a map with lat and longitude (0,0), i can't get the current position because i get this error:

09-16 12:06:46.515: ERROR/MapActivity(464): Couldn't get connection factory client

The apikey is correct, i've also reinstalled eclipse + android sdk and regenerate another debug.keystore and its relative apikey, but nothing changed..

The source is this (note that i dont see the println on logcat                  System.out.println("*** i'm here"+current_lat));

### :

```
package it.me.map;


import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;

import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.location.LocationProvider;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import it.man.app.R;

public class Maps extends MapActivity 
{    
    private TextView tvName;
    private TextView tvAddress;
    private TextView tvOpenTime;

    private MapController mc;
    private MapView mapView;

    private static double current_lat;
    private static double current_long;

    private static LocationListener mNetworkListener = new LocationListener() 
{   
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                    makeUseOfNewLocation(location);
            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}

            public void makeUseOfNewLocation(Location location) {
                    current_lat = location.getLatitude();
                    current_long = location.getLongitude();
                    System.out.println("*** i'm here"+current_lat);
            }
};


   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.maps);
       mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
       mc = mapView.getController();

       LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
       mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mNetworkListener);

       GeoPoint p = new GeoPoint((int)current_lat*(1000000), (int)current_long*(1000000));            
       mc.animateTo(p);

 }

   @Override
   protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
       return false;
   }
}
```

the maps.xml it's this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mapview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:apiKey="02pmISdykDhJpseMz_d3XLv5ojPsNW25Tz9dtdA"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and finally the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="ir.marco.furesta"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />


    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
  <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
  <activity android:name=".Maps"></activity>


  <activity android:name=".NewsList"></activity>

    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" /> 
</manifest>
```

Comment: change you version with 2.1 and in manifest replace version 8 to 7 and then try

Comment: Whatever your problem is (and your description of the problem is not very clear), it has nothing to do with that message. You get that message all of the time. Note that `LocationListener` has nothing whatsoever to do with a map.

Comment: @Pratik - changed version with google apis 2.1 and minSdkVersion now is 7, but i get the same error

Comment: @CommonsWare so what i'm supposed to do to fill current_lat and current_lon with the current gps coordinates?

Comment: @androidc0d: Fill them in `onLocationChanged()`.

Comment: onLocationChanged() already do it by calling makeUseOfNewLocation(), but onLocationChanged isn't called (and i'm asking why).

Comment: @androidc0d did you ever figure this issue out? I'm have a similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23568821/mapactivity-couldnt-get-connection-factory-client-v1

Answer (score -1):

I think you forget to specify the api key in manifest and just add this permission

```
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
```

add api key like this.

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="Your api key"/>
```

This code worked for me.

```
    public class LocTrack extends Service implements LocationListener {

        LocationManager lm;
        public double lat, lon;

        public boolean InitGPS() {

            LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

            if (!lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
                Toast.makeText(LocTrack.this, "Please Enable GPS!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent gps = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                startActivity(gps);
                return false;
            }
            lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 2000, 10, this);
            return true;
        }

        public void StopGPS() {
            lm.removeUpdates(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location l) {

            Storage.lat = l.getLatitude();
            Storage.lon = l.getLongitude();


            Storage.changed = true;
            Toast.makeText(LocTrack.this,"location",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            InitGPS();
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            StopGPS();
        }

        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }


        @Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
            super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
            InitGPS();
            return START_STICKY;
        }
    }
```

I used this fragment for displaying map.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```